# Maven War Plugin - add external resources from another jar

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

If I wanted to pull out a resource from another jar, say an image or XML file, is that possible?  Would I use the Maven Assembly Plugin or the War Plugin to do this?  I want it to end up in a WAR file.

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin in your war module and bind the **[`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html)** goal to the **`generate-resources`** phase. Check the [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) example.

Comment: Awesome, that sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 1):

I want to extract some resource form artefactory to used in other proyect, we need 2 plugins maven-dependency-plugin to extract and maven-clean-plugin to clean proyect. call first plugin execute the goal dependency:unpack.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.company.artifactory</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <includes>dirInsideJar/**/*.*</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <!-- other configurations here -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/dirInsideJar</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The usage of the above is explained in [this article](http://jvm-java.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/maven-how-external-resource-extract.html).

Comment: explain in http://jvm-java.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/maven-how-external-resource-extract.html

Comment: This answer could be improved greatly by giving a brief overview rather than just providing an article link - in case the link is broken at some future date.